# iOS app flow chart tool

Tags: ios, ios5, workflow, flowchart

I'm looking for application that can help me create flow chart for iOS app that includes views. An example:

http://yvonnelao.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/RW_FlowChart_121410.jpg

Is there a built solution for this already or should I go manual drawing?

Answer (score 2):

One commercial wireframing tool for iOS I've seen a number of my clients use is [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups).  It's $80 for a single user license, though.